# Help identifying kanji

Tags: kanji

This is from a manga for general readers so should not be too obscure.

[image]

It looks like 氵+ 益 but I can’t find a full match when looking up by components.

溢{あふ}れる seems to match by okurigana and context but it looks quite different visually. Is that some variant or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the difference in form, it's 溢【あふ】れる.

See entries at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%BA%A2), [WWWJIDIC](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1MMC%E6%BA%A2), [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%BA%A2), [Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%BA%A2-433905).  And specific for just the glyph, see also [Unihan](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%E6%BA%A2), [Chise](http://www.chise.org/est/view/character/%E6%BA%A2), and [Glyph Wiki](https://glyphwiki.org/wiki/u6ea2). These last three show the variants better.

Comment: FWIW, Unihan is often one of my first online go-to resources for figuring out a kanji (if I can access it in copy-paste-able form).

Comment: Thanks! Can you expand a bit on the top two strokes, why do they flip direction? Does 益 have similar variants and if not, why?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky: Looks like 益 does have variants that fit with the 溢 character shape: [entry at Glyph Wiki](https://glyphwiki.org/wiki/u76ca).

Comment: See also the top of [the Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%9B%8A) showing the variants, and [the "Glyph origin" section](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%9B%8A#Glyph_origin). Apparently the set of strokes above the 皿 glyph were originally from 水.

Comment: This happens a lot when you have one example that got updated and it's a jouyou kanji, like 益, and other kanji that use the same element are not jouyou kanji , like 溢. You may see the non-jouyou ones updated or not updated.

Comment: The top of 益 is 水 turned sideways (check out the variant 㳑). Kangxi character forms don’t like 丷 on the top of characters and so will flip them around to 八.

Comment: Sorry to spam your mentions again but I just found that the recommended form got changed [in JIS X0213:2004](https://kakijun.jp/main/jis2004.html) so possibly the manga was simply typed using an old font.